# How to insert Latitude and Longitude inside SQLite database - React Native

Tags: react-native, sqlite

I am not able to save the Latitude and Longitude values into the SQLite database. What kind of type of data they are? I tried to insert them as REAL, BLOB, NUMERIC, and TEXT but they are not saved correctly.
This is my code:

```
const createTable = () => {
        db.transaction((tx) => {
            tx.executeSql(
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
                + "Users "
                + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Title TEXT, Description TEXT, Latitude TEXT);"
            )
        })
    }
  //in the following function I want to insert Latitude into Users and display it in the console.log
  

    const setData = async () => {
          try {
            dispatch(setTitle(title));
            Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(info => dispatch(setLat(info.coords.latitude)));
    
            console.log('latitudine:',lat); // i have my current latitude
              await db.transaction(async (tx) => {
                await tx.executeSql(
                    "INSERT INTO Users (Title, Latitude) VALUES (?,?)",
                    [title, lat]
                );
            }); 
            await db.transaction(async (tx) => { 
              await tx.executeSql(
                "SELECT Title, Latitude FROM Users",
                    [],
                    (tx, results) => {
                         len = results.rows.length; 
                        if (len > 0) {
                          for (let i=0;i<len;i++){
                            var userTitle = results.rows.item(i).Title;
                            var userLatitude = results.rows.item(i).Latitude; 
                            console.log('userTitle: ',userTitle); // no display
                            console.log('Latitude from database: ',userLatitude); //no display
                          }
                        }
                    }
                )
            });
          } catch (error) {
              console.log(error);
          }
         }
```

If I don't add the Latitude column in the database, the function works correctly and the `userTitle` is displayed correctly. I think the problem comes from the Latitude's column type but I am not sure of this.
Someone can help me please? Very thanks!

Edit: if I have only 3 columns (ID, Title, Latitude) and latitude has values saved as a string I have no problem (thanks Hitesh Prajapati!). But... if I add a column in the database (for example Longitude), I have the problem again. In particular when I have to insert the new value inside the Longitude column. How can I solve this? Thanks

Comment: you have to convert values into string. try that !!

Comment: I edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Hitesh Prajapati in a comment on the question, the latitude would need to be converted to a string before being saved in the SQLite db - based on the type defined for its column.

From the docs, [getCurrentPosition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation) returns an object whose `coords` property is a [GeolocationCoordinates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GeolocationCoordinates) object with its `longitude` and `latitude` fields as the *double* type.

So, if you define the column for latitude as `Latitude TEXT`, then you need to convert the latitude to a string. The same would be required for the *longitude* column if the column type is set to TEXT:

```
...
// This assumes lat is assigned the value from info.coords.latitude
// And longitude is assigned the value from info.coords.longitude
await tx.executeSql(
    "INSERT INTO Users (Title, Latitude, Longitude) VALUES (?,?)",
    [title, lat.toString(), longitude.toString()]
);
...
```